# Instalação do Atom Text Editor

Tags: node.js, github, instalador, atom

Descobri um novo editor de código há pouco tempo, o [Atom](https://atom.io), que está na plataforma [GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/). A minha dúvida prende-se com a instalação deste editor e quanto à [documentação que dão](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/os-x.md). Tenho que instalar o Node.js ou simplesmente descarregar o Atom e instalar?

P.S: Não tenho muitos conhecimentos de GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Os dois. O node.js se faz necessario para que o Atom seja executado corretamente.